# concurrent_hash_map results in compiling error

Tags: c++, concurrency, hashmap

I are trying to solve an problem related to hash_maps. Since I have huge data and concurrent read/write access to normal hash_map, I have decided to use tbb concurrent_hash_map. It is an Intel library. We are expecting to get better read/write concurrency after using this.

But we could not go forward much. Below is the problem:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "tbb/concurrent_hash_map.h"

using namespace tbb;
using namespace std;

typedef concurrent_hash_map<long int,char*> data_hash;

int main(){
  data_hash dh;
  data_hash::accessor a;

  long int k=10; 
  dh.insert(a,k);
  a->second="hello";
  for(data_hash::iterator j=dh.begin();j!=dh.end(); ++j){ 
    std::cout << "%lu %s\n",j->first,j->second;
  }
  if(dh.find(a,9)) {
    std::cout << "true\n";
  } else {
    std::cout << "false\n";            
  }
  a.release();
  return 0;
}
```

While compiling with g++, I get following error:

> In function `tbb::spin_rw_mutex_v3::scoped_lock::acquire(tbb::spin_rw_mutex_v3&, bool)':
>   demochashmap.cpp:(.text._ZN3tbb16spin_rw_mutex_v311scoped_lock7acquireERS0_b
>   [tbb::spin_rw_mutex_v3::scoped_lock::acquire(tbb::spin_rw_mutex_v3&, bool)]+0x3c): undefined reference to`tbb::spin_rw_mutex_v3::internal_acquire_writer()'
>   demochashmap.cpp:(.text._ZN3tbb16spin_rw_mutex_v311scoped_lock7acquireERS0_b[tbb::spin_rw_mutex_v3::scoped_lock::acquire(tbb::spin_rw_mutex_v3&, bool)]+0x4d): undefined reference to `tbb::spin_rw_mutex_v3::internal_acquire_reader()'
>   /tmp/ccguvcnD.o: In function`tbb::spin_rw_mutex_v3::scoped_lock::upgrade_to_writer()':
>   demochashmap.cpp:(.text._ZN3tbb16spin_rw_mutex_v311scoped_lock17upgrade_to_writerEv[tbb::spin_rw_mutex_v3::scoped_lock::upgrade_to_writer()]+0x1f): undefined reference to `tbb::spin_rw_mutex_v3::internal_upgrade()'

I understand that program is not seeing the definition of mentioned function in the error message. From our understanding, included file "    #include "tbb/concurrent_hash_map.h"" should be sufficient.

Not sure what should I try.

References: https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/506077

Comment: I don't see the complete error message.

Comment: @Surt, Added more information about the compilation error message.

Comment: What is your `g++` compilation command? _Undefined reference_ is typically not a compilation error but a linker error. Linking TBB library should help. Try `-L$TBB_PATH -ltbb`, where `TBB_PATH` is a path to TBB libs.